# Is linq more efficient than it appears on the surface?

Tags: c#, linq

If I write something like this:

```
var things = mythings
    .Where(x => x.IsSomeValue)
    .Where(y => y.IsSomeOtherValue)
```

Is this the same as:

```
var results1 = new List<Thing>();
foreach(var t in mythings)
    if(t.IsSomeValue)
        results1.Add(t);

var results2 = new List<Thing>();
foreach(var t in results1)
    if(t.IsSomeOtherValue)
        results2.Add(t);
```

Or is there some magic under the covers that works more like this:

```
var results = new List<Thing>();
foreach(var t in mythings)
    if(t.IsSomeValue && t.IsSomeOtherValue)
        results.Add(t);
```

Or is it something completely different altogether?

Comment: You can view this in ILSpy.

Comment: It's more like the second example than the first but second ChaosPandion's answer that ILSpy is your friend.

Comment: See also [Why are Where and Select outperforming just Select?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18331774)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

LINQ queries are **lazy**. That means the code:

```
var things = mythings
    .Where(x => x.IsSomeValue)
    .Where(y => y.IsSomeOtherValue);
```

does very little. The original enumerable (`mythings`) is only enumerated when the resulting enumerable (`things`) is consumed, e.g. by a `foreach` loop, `.ToList()`, or `.ToArray()`.

If you call `things.ToList()`, it is roughly equivalent to your latter code, with perhaps some (usually insignificant) overhead from the enumerators.

Likewise, if you use a foreach loop:

```
foreach (var t in things)
    DoSomething(t);
```

It is similar in performance to:

```
foreach (var t in mythings)
    if (t.IsSomeValue && t.IsSomeOtherValue)
        DoSomething(t);
```

Some of the performance advantages of the laziness approach for enumerables (as opposed to calculating all the results and storing them in a list) are that it uses very little memory (since only one result is stored at a time) and that there's no significant up-front cost.

If the enumerable is only partially enumerated, this is especially important. Consider this code:

```
things.First();
```

The way LINQ is implemented, `mythings` will only be enumerated up to the first element that matches your where conditions. If that element is early on in the list, this can be a huge performance boost (e.g. O(1) instead of O(n)).

Comment: One performance difference between LINQ and the equivalent code using `foreach` is that LINQ uses delegate invocations, that have some overhead. This can be significant when the conditions execute very quickly (which they often do).

Comment: That's what I meant by enumerator overhead. It can be an issue in some (rare) cases, but in my experience that isn't very often - usually the time it takes is very small to begin with, or it is far outweighed by other operations you're doing.

Comment: A nasty limitation of Linq's lazy evaluation is that there's no way to take a "snapshot" of an enumeration except via methods like `ToList` or `ToArray`.  If such a thing had been properly built into `IEnumerable`, it would have been possible to ask a list to "snapshot" any aspects that might change in future without having to generate everything.

Answer (score 7):

The following code :

```
var things = mythings
    .Where(x => x.IsSomeValue)
    .Where(y => y.IsSomeOtherValue);
```

Is equivalent to nothing, because of the lazy evaluation, nothing will happen.

```
var things = mythings
    .Where(x => x.IsSomeValue)
    .Where(y => y.IsSomeOtherValue)
    .ToList();
```

Is different, because the evaluation will be launch.

Each item of `mythings` will be given to the first `Where`. If it passes, it will be given to the second `Where`. If it passes, it will be part of the output.

So this looks like more like this :

```
var results = new List<Thing>();
foreach(var t in mythings)
{
    if(t.IsSomeValue)
    {
        if(t.IsSomeOtherValue)
        {
            results.Add(t);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Deferred execution aside (which the other answers already explain, I'll just point out another detail), it's more like in your second example.

Let's just imagine you call `ToList` on `things`.

The implementation of `Enumerable.Where` returns a `Enumerable.WhereListIterator`. When you call `Where` on that `WhereListIterator` (a.k.a. chaining `Where`-calls), you no longer call `Enumerable.Where`, but `Enumerable.WhereListIterator.Where`, which actually combines the predicates (using `Enumerable.CombinePredicates`).

So it's more like `if(t.IsSomeValue && t.IsSomeOtherValue)`.

Comment: "returns a Enumerable.WhereListIterator" made it click for me. Probably a very simple concept, but that's what I was overlooking with ILSpy. Thanks

Comment: See [Jon Skeet's re-implementation of this optimization](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/06/16/linq-to-objects-and-the-performance-of-nested-quot-where-quot-calls.aspx) if you're interested in a more in depth analysis.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not the same. In your example `things` is an `IEnumerable`, which at this point is still only an iterator, not an actual array or list. Moreover since `things` is not used, the loop is never even evaluated. The type `IEnumerable` allows to iterate through elements `yield`-ed by Linq instructions and process them further with more instructions, which means in the end you really have only one loop.

But as soon as you add an instruction like `.ToArray()` or `.ToList()`, you're ordering the creation of an actual data structure, thus putting bounds to your chain.

See this related SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789389/how-do-i-implement-ienumerable